# Объединение двух анимаций CSS

Tags: css3, css-animation

У меня есть красный блок `<div class="box"></div>`

И я хочу заставить его двигаться сначала на ***150px*** по `оси X`, а затем сразу же двигаться по `оси Y` на ***100px***.

Но по итогу выполняется только одна анимация.

Как объединить эти две анимации?

```css
  .box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f00;
  -webkit-animation: traX 0.5s linear, traY 0.5s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes traX {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes traY {
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f00;
  animation: traX 0.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes traX {
  50% {
    transform: translate(150px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(150px, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответы

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

100% это конечная точка + у тебя вложенность анимации какаето странная.
Начальная точка полюбому должна быть другой. Что-то по типу такого.

```css
.box {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #f00;
-webkit-animation: traX 0.5s linear, traY 0.5s linear;  
animation-duration: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes traX {
50% {
      -webkit-transform: translate(150px,0);
      }
      100% {
      -webkit-transform: translate(150px,100px);
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: При данной анимации блок пойдет сначала по оси X, а затем по диагонали . Мне же надо чтобы сначала блок пошел по оси X, а затем уже от измененного положения по оси Y.

Comment: @trigsen сделал правку, так нужно?